# How do I call a member function from componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to call a function from componentDidMount() after getCurrentPosition() is called. If I pass position to updatePosition the app crashes. If I move the contents of the updatePosition function into getCurrentPosition() then it works. What do I need to do to be able to call a member function from within componentDidMount().

```
class GeolocationViewer extends Component { 
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        lat: 0,
        long: 0,
        heading: 0,
        accuracy: 0,
        speed: 0,
        pointCount: 0
      };
  }

  updatePostion(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    this.setState({lat});
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let self = this;

    setInterval(() => {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        // this breaks
        this.updatePostion(position);

        // if I place the body of updatePosition here it works.
      },
       (error) => {},
       {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 10000}
      );
    }, 5000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
        <View style={{flex: 1, color: 'green'}}>
          <Text style={styles.green}>
            Position: {this.state.lat}, {this.state.long}
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.green}>
            Heading: {this.state.heading}
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.green}>
            Speed: {this.state.speed}
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.green}>
            Accuracy: {this.state.accuracy}
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.green}>
            Point Count: {this.state.pointCount}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it all works! Here is an [RNplay example](https://rnplay.org/apps/in5qUw) and its code:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var {
  Component,
} = React;
var ReactNative = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} = ReactNative;

class GeolocationViewer extends Component { 
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        lat: 0,
        long: 0,
        heading: 0,
        accuracy: 0,
        speed: 0,
        pointCount: 0
      };
  }

  updatePostion(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    this.setState({lat});
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        this.updatePostion(position);
      },
       (error) => {},
       {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 10000}
      );
    }, 5000);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 30}}>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <Text>
            Position: {this.state.lat}, {this.state.long}
          </Text>
          <Text>
            Heading: {this.state.heading}
          </Text>
          <Text>
            Speed: {this.state.speed}
          </Text>
          <Text>
            Accuracy: {this.state.accuracy}
          </Text>
          <Text>
            Point Count: {this.state.pointCount}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => GeolocationViewer);
```

(check the Console Logs)

Answer (score 0):

'self' is not defined inside of updatePostion() that's why you have the error

```
updatePostion(position) {
    // replace self with this
    self.setState({position.coords.latitude});
}
```

also you don't need this

```
let self = this;
```

inside of componentDidMount() since you use arrow functions

Comment: That was me being careless when posting the question. I still have the error even with the updated code (I edited the post).

Comment: Which exactly error do you have? Btw, you have a typo in function name: updatePo*sti*on (postion instead of position). Maybe in your real code you define the function as updatePosition, but call it with incorrect name?

Answer (score 0):

I know this looks ugly, but this is the common issue when you work on react you will face. bind member function inside `constructor` (ES7 may make it look better, but that will be long time wait)

```
constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        lat: 0,
        long: 0,
        heading: 0,
        accuracy: 0,
        speed: 0,
        pointCount: 0
      };

      // in your constructor, add this binding
      this.updatePostion = this.updatePostion.bind(this)
  }
```